# Can someone please give working example of interface in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I am getting error "This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created." while using interface in solidity can someone help me on this or please give me working example of interface in solidity?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

interface Audit {
    function CheckBlance() public returns(bool);
    function lending() public returns(bool);
}

contract Fin_Inst is Audit{
    uint public Money;

    function Fin_Inst(uint Value) public {
        Money = Value;
    }

    function Deposit(uint DepAmount) public{
        Money = Money + DepAmount; 
    }

    function Withdraw(uint WithdAmount) public{
        if(CheckBlance(WithdAmount) == true){
            Money = Money - WithdAmount;
        }

    }

    function Balance() public constant returns (uint){
        return Money;
    }

    function CheckBlance(uint WithdAmount) public returns (bool){
        return Money >= WithdAmount;
    }

    function lending() public returns (bool){
        return Money > 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made small changes and now when you run Create `Fin_Inst` it executes without any error messages.

Seems like an error was in function parameter in interface method `CheckBalance(uint WithdAmount)`.

---

Here is the **edited code**:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

interface Audit {
    function CheckBalance(uint WithdAmount) public view returns(bool);
    function lending() public view returns(bool);
}

contract Fin_Inst is Audit{
    uint public Money;

    function Fin_Inst(uint Value) public {
        Money = Value;
    }

    function Deposit(uint DepAmount) public {
        Money = Money + DepAmount; 
    }

    function Withdraw(uint WithdAmount) public {
        if(CheckBalance(WithdAmount) == true){
            Money = Money - WithdAmount;
        }
    }

    function Balance() external view returns (uint) {
        return Money;
    }

    function CheckBalance(uint WithdAmount) public view returns (bool) {
        return Money >= WithdAmount;
    }

    function lending() public view returns (bool) {
        return Money > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to implement a method you must respect the signature (same name and params) completly.

For example, you can have in your Contract 3 different methods like 
`method1()`, `method1(unit x)` and `method1(unit[] xs)`

To implement this interface, you must code the 3 methods in the child Contract. So, if you only implement `method1()` they are still pending `method1(unit x)` and `method1(unit[] xs)`.

This is called [Function overloading](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#function-overloading). Therefore `CheckBalance(uint WithdAmount)` is not the same as `CheckBalance()`